# Xubuntu 16.04 - All HDMI audio options appear Unplugged

Tags: nvidia, sound, xubuntu, hdmi

I have an NVidia GeForce GTX 960 card and an BenQ HDMI monitor and the sound works without any issues on Windows, but when I boot into Xubuntu, I cant hear any audio, all HDA NVidia configuration says Unplugged, [see the screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4wmc.png)

I installed Gnome ALSA mixer only to find out that the controls for NVidia device are missing, [check the screenshot of that here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hagxz.png).

This is the content of /proc/asound/card1:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 codec#0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 eld#0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 eld#0.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 eld#0.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 eld#0.3
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 id
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 pcm3p/
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 pcm7p/
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 pcm8p/
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Oct  8 00:15 pcm9p/
```

The contents of the eld* files.

```
$ cat eld#0.0
monitor_present     0
eld_valid       0
$ cat eld#0.1
monitor_present     0
eld_valid       0
$ cat eld#0.2
monitor_present     0
eld_valid       0
$ cat eld#0.3
monitor_present     0
eld_valid       0
```

I have had a look at this:

```
 download.nvidia.com/XFree86/gpu-hdmi-audio-document/gpu-hdmi-audio.html
```

but I could have missed something, but I think its the ELD. I am not sure if NVidia drivers are compatible with BenQ monitor.

Any ideas on solving this, anyone else facing similar issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the link that I could not post in my question due to restriction of first time poster: ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/gpu-hdmi-audio-document/gpu-hdmi-audio.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing drivers from Nvidia website, it now recognises my monitor correctly as well. Anyone who's facing similar problem should completely uninstall the nvidia drivers provider by Canonical/Ubuntu and install the latest from Nvidia site.

Steps on this page:
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/02/how-to-install-nvidia-361-28-stable-graphics-drivers-in-linux.html

These steps are applicable to any driver & Linux version.

Contents of eld#0.1 after installing drivers:

```
$ cat eld#0.1
monitor_present     1
eld_valid       1
monitor_name        BenQ GL2250H
connection_type     HDMI
eld_version     [0x2] CEA-861D or below
edid_version        [0x3] CEA-861-B, C or D
manufacture_id      0xd109
product_id      0x78a1
port_id         0x0
support_hdcp        0
support_ai      0
audio_sync_delay    0
speakers        [0x1] FL/FR
sad_count       1
sad0_coding_type    [0x1] LPCM
sad0_channels       2
sad0_rates      [0xe0] 32000 44100 48000
sad0_bits       [0xe0000] 16 20 24
```